# *Very specific issue* of removing white spaces from multiple lines of a single string in C#. Trim() not working

Tags: c#, string, format, whitespace

I am working with C#. I had a string which was in the format:

```
myString = ""Person:Name","Address:City","University:District""
```

I know having quotes within a main string quote is not right in C# and that you have to escape quotes. But this string that I have here is the result of concatenation of several strings to make it look like that for some back-end processing.It was a string list of the format [A:B, C:D, E:F] which was converted into JSON format and then back to string again. I stripped off the external brackets already in case you're wondering. So before moving further, I'd like to clarify that this is a legal string and the quotes within the string are not a problem in this particular scenario.

I want my final output to display in multiple lines like the following:

```
Person:Name
Address:City
University:District
```

I tried to achieve it by doing the following:

```
 myString = myString.Replace(',', '\n');  //replaced comma with newline
 myString = myString.Replace('"', ' ');   //replaced double quote with a space
```

I have them in separate lines now, however my problem now is I can't seem to get rid of the space. I want all of the spaces removed. i.e 6 total below. Turns out Trim() does not help me. Is there a way to solve this? This is where I am at right now. I'm open to trying any new idea if my way is not correct. If you're confused with the way the string is, you can ask me.

```
(space)Person:Name(space)
(space)Address:City(space)
(space)University:District(space)
```

Comment: Try replacing the double quote with an "empty" string like `myString = myString.Replace('"', '');`

Comment: @maxbeaudoin That doesn't compile, you cannot use the empty character literal

Comment: It would have been much easier if you had just read the original JSON into a `Dictionary<string, string>`, `foreach`-ed over it and printed it line by line

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto use the string version `"".Replace("", "")`

Comment: Use a [JSON parser](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and stop trying to parse JSON as if it were a string.

Comment: This is an XY problem. *Please help me fix the Y problem I created myself by not properly handling the X problem in the first place.* The best thing to do is stop now, scrap what you've done so far, and ask how to solve the X problem instead.

Comment: @maxbeaudoin using the string version helped me! thanks!

Comment: As has been touched on by some of the others, the actual correct answer is to read in the string and not try to pull it apart piece by piece.  JSON parsing libraries (either built in or 3rd party) will do a much better job of this than trying to reinvent the wheel yourself.  What happens if you run into special characters within your data?  a parsing library should deal with this rather gracefully, while manually pulling apart the string likely will not.

Answer (score -1):

You are replacing double quotes with a space here.

```
myString = myString.Replace('"', ' ');
```

It should be like this :

```
myString = myString.Replace('"', '');
```